# Visual Studio 2013 Typescript Integration broken

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have the very weird bug that Typescript support has entirely disappeared from my Visual Studio 2013 Professional (Update 3).

It's like VS2013 never knew how to handle TS files. I have no syntax highlighting, no autocompletion, no compile-on-save, nothing.

Typescript settings even disappeared from Tools -> Options -> Text-Editor. No trace of TS anywhere.

I've reinstalled VS. I've uninstalled every extension. I've installed the TS Power Tool. I'm at my wits end.

I've searched all across the internet and nobody seems to have this problem.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you still have tsc.exe? It should present here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe

Comment: Yes, the exe is still present.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing TypeScript 1.1?  It's available at https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/37f81de4-35dd-47de-8ae9-795112dcfc75 .  I've found it stable enough for production use.

Comment: I've tried installing it but it doesn't change anything in VS13. Still no support to be found anywhere.